# Release maven project removing automatically SNAPSHOT dependencies

Tags: maven, snapshot, maven-release-plugin

I want to make my first release of a multi-module maven project using the maven release plugin. I´m facing a problem in the release:prepare step because I have SNAPSHOT dependencies.

```
<project ...> 

   <parent>
      <artifactId>project</artifactId>
      <groupId>ccc.aaa.bbb</groupId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </parent>

  <artifactId>common</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>common</name>

  <modules>
     <module>daoModule</module>
     <module>configModule</module>
     <module>exceptionModule</module>
  </modules>

   <scm>
     ...    
   </scm>
   <distributionManagement>
       <repository>...</repository>
       <snapshotRepository>...</snapshotRepository>
   </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

And the modules extend this as its parent:

```
<project ...>
<parent>
   <artifactId>common</artifactId>
   <groupId>ccc.aaa.bbb</groupId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>exceptionModule</artifactId>
  <name>exceptionModule</name>

<build>
        ...
```

The plugin changes the the version of the artifact 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT to a release version 0.0.1 ,  and creates the new snapshot version id 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.

¿Is there any way to change automatically the **version of the parents** from 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT to  0.0.1 - the release that is going to be created-?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work when doing `release:prepare` from the aggregator project level that contains all the modules you're interested in. So your `common`, `project` artifacts and all the modules should be released at once. Also look at `autoVersionSubmodules` switch to do a little less typing.

Comment: When doing the release:prepare from the aggregator project is when it fails because the second step of the release:prepare checks that there are no SNAPSHOT dependencies [link](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html) . I'll check the autoVersionSubmodules if the version property of the parent is not inherit when creating the artifact. Thx

Comment: Yes, I know it, but these `SNAPSHOT` dependencies that are inherited by modules internally within build reactor should be resolved a little more smart. Works for me for several years. Most of my projects are multimodule and I usually release them this way. One requirement: all these projects have to be build at once within same build reactor!

Comment: You are right, my problem is that I don't have all the projects in the same reactor because I_ want to avoid memory problems. I have made some test building the projects within the same reactor and the plugin works perfect. I'll try to find some manual workaround... Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi again, I was wondering if there is any possibility of tell maven-release-plugin all the modules involved in order to do the release in the same reactor but without changin the pom, maybe with Build Helper Maven Plugin?